# Flutter/Dart how to check if the app is paid or free version from PlayStore?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I want my app to have a free and a paid version and I want to use one code for both. I need a way to know from the code when I start the app wether the user has a free or a paid version of the app.
I do not have a backend part/server nor is there a login on my app, you do not need to make an account to use it.

All the solutions I come across is for when you have in app purchase, but I only have that one time purchase which is not done in the app but on PlayStore. I found a solution for iOS that is sending a request to
http.get(Uri.parse('https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt')); //you change this to your app later, this is a test link
and then in response if in_app list is empty user has a free version
Is there a similair solution for Android and can someone verify or give suggestions for the iOS one?

Thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest reading this https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors

Answer (score 1):

You can build the app twice with a different bundleId for each build. This way you can check in your app the bundleId and see if it's the paid version or not